# When having 3 threads, how do you make that one thread sleep for 0.2 seconds longer than the others in java?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I have 3 threads:

Jamaica 
 Fiji 
 Hawaii 
 All threads output themselves when they wake from sleep.

I want Hawaii to sleep 0.2 seconds longer than the rest and as the code continues it sleeps .2 seconds after the other. Example: Sleep 0.2 secs long outputs, Sleep again 0.4 secs long outs puts, sleeps again 0.6 seconds long, and so on.

```
enter code here
    public class Tw {

Tw( int t){


}


    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new S
               ("Jamaica").start();
        new S("Fiji").start();

        new S("Hawaii").start();

    }
}
        class S extends Thread {

   String whatever;
  public S(String str) {
super(str);
}
public void run() {
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + " " + getName());
        try {
        sleep((int)(Math.random() * 1000));;

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
}

System.out.println("DONE! " + getName());
}
```

}

The output:
   0 Jamaica
   0 Hawaii
  0 Fiji
   1 Jamaica
   1 Hawaii
   2 Jamaica
  1 Fiji
2 Fiji
3 Jamaica
4 Jamaica
3 Fiji
2 Hawaii
5 Jamaica
4 Fiji
3 Hawaii
4 Hawaii
5 Hawaii
6 Jamaica
7 Jamaica
5 Fiji
6 Hawaii
6 Fiji
8 Jamaica
7 Fiji
7 Hawaii
8 Fiji
9 Jamaica
8 Hawaii
9 Fiji
9 Hawaii
DONE! Jamaica
DONE! Fiji
DONE! Hawaii

Comment: Pass a parameter into the constructor of S that controls the length of the sleep.

Comment: You can make a thread sleep longer, but the exact delay won't be guaranteed

Comment: I really really doubt that what you describe is actually what you want.  You can easily and reliably reproduce your results, with a ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, running a single thread.